# Teaspoon error while testing simple script

Tags: jasmine, teaspoon

I am testing below code logic:

```
handleOnMediaPlaying: function(event){
  // body...
  if(isAd){
    if(event.data.percentComplete >= 25 && !firstQuartileFlag){
      firstQuartileFlag = true;
    }
    if(event.data.percentComplete >= 50 && !midpointflag){
      midpointflag = true;
    }
    if(event.data.percentComplete >= 75 && !thirdQuartileFlag){
      thirdQuartileFlag = true;
    }
  }
},
```

Function 'handleOnMediaPlaying' is inside an object pdkHandler. Also, there is another function handleOnMediaStart in pdhHandler where i define the variables isAd (if media is an ad), firstQuartileFlag (set to false), midpointflag (set to false) and thirdQuartileFlag (set to false).
I have written following spec for the same but it fails with an error saying "expected false to be true". Below is the spec....

describe("handleOnMediaPlaying", function(){

```
beforeEach(function(){
  isAd = true;
  firstQuartileFlag = false;
  midpointflag = false;
  thirdQuartileFlag = false; 
  spyOn(pdkHandler, 'handleOnMediaPlaying');
});

it('sets firstQuartileFlag to true on percentComplete = 26 ', function(){
  var eventAd = {
    data: {
      percentComplete: 26
    }
  };
  pdkHandler.handleOnMediaPlaying(eventAd);
  expect(firstQuartileFlag).toBe(true);
});

it('sets midpointflag to true ', function(){
  var eventAd = {
    data: {
      percentComplete: 50
    }
  };
  pdkHandler.handleOnMediaPlaying(eventAd);
  expect(midpointflag).toBe(true);
});


it('sets thirdQuartileFlag to true ', function(){
  var eventAd = {
    data: {
      percentComplete: 76
    }
  };
  pdkHandler.handleOnMediaPlaying(eventAd);
  expect(thirdQuartileFlag).toBe(true);
});
```

});

I have no idea why it is failing when everything is straight forward. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, the   spyOn(pdkHandler, 'handleOnMediaPlaying'); method was holding the execution of the function handleOnMediaPlaying and hence the value was not being set to expected true.
Hope this helps some newbies like me.